# How to dynamically create and set a validation model for a FastAPI endpoint based on the dependencies I'm passing?

Tags: python, oop, dependency-injection, fastapi, pydantic

In the example below, I'd like to loose the coupling between `MediaController` and its dependencies, the `MediaPipelineX`s to enable it to work with whatever I'm passing to it. That's an important aspect of OOP and Dependency Injection.

How do I do that? The way fastapi currently works seems to make reuse of `MediaController` impossible. I feel if [`add_api_route`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/routing.py#L843) would take another parameter `request_model` I could create the type in the class initializer and provide it as instance attribute. But without, I feel stuck.

I'd appreciate any advice.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal, Union


class MediaPipeline1():
    class Params1(BaseModel):
        pipeline_name: Literal["One"]
        foo: int = 11

class MediaPipeline2():
    class Params2(BaseModel):
        pipeline_name: Literal["Two"]
        bar: int = 22

class MediaPipeline3():
    class Params3(BaseModel):
        pipeline_name: Literal["Three"]
        baz: int = 33

##############################################

class MediaController():
    # Hardcode the dependencies the initializer gets passed
    # This is bad
    class RequestModel(BaseModel): # Tagged union
        params: Union[MediaPipeline1.Params1, MediaPipeline2.Params2] = Field(discriminator='pipeline_name')

    def __init__(self, pipelines):
        self.pipelines = pipelines

    def handler(self, request: RequestModel):
        print(request)

#############################################

my_pipeline_1 = MediaPipeline1()
my_pipeline_2 = MediaPipeline2()
my_pipeline_3 = MediaPipeline3()

router = APIRouter()

# Works
my_controller_12 = MediaController([my_pipeline_1, my_pipeline_2])
router.add_api_route("/1", my_controller_12.handler)

# Bug: Will not handle my_pipeline_3 because class is hardcoded for [my_pipeline_1, my_pipeline_2]
my_controller_23 = MediaController([my_pipeline_2, my_pipeline_3])
router.add_api_route("/2", my_controller_23.handler)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: [`pydantic.create_model()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#dynamic-model-creation) is what you want, I guess

Comment: @sudden_appearance: Yes but how do I use that dynamicallly created model as function parameter type hint?

Comment: `self.RequestModel = create_model(...)` inside `MediaController.__init__()` will generate object specific variable with proper types and you will be able to use that.

Comment: @sudden_appearance: How do I reference that dynamically created type in the function parameter type hint? Please tell me exactly. Note that this is a instance method, not a freestanding function. In a freenstanding function it works, but not in an instance method. https://bpa.st/K2SA

Comment: Using example in your paste, it looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/FXPnuYxD). Note that it is `@app.post("/")`, not `get`, since GET request does not have body

Comment: @sudden_appearance: As said, in a freestanding function (that is, one that doesn't belong to a class) it works. Your suggestion works fine but becomes impractical once there are more handlers in play. Being able to just instantiate `MediaController` and have everything set up is what makes Classes so appealing. But, thinking about your example, I think a solution has sparked in my mind. I could create a `Media.Controller.create_handlers()` function that creates the `handler()` function(s) at runtime, at attaches them to its object. Need to try if it works, though. Thank you!